# r: Retaining warnings in `sapply` loop as a vector

Tags: r, dplyr, warnings, sapply

I'm transforming my data using my own function as following:

```
my_df %>% [...] %>%
  mutate(my_result = sapply(id_column, my_function))
```

Here, `my_function` will perform some computation for each row that returns a numeric result. The function cannot (easily) be vectorized, which is why I'm relying on sapply. So far, so good.

Sometimes, `my_function` will throw a warning, indicating that a specific result should be taken with a grain of salt.

I would like to capture these warnings, and append them to my dataframe in a new column. Expected result:

`id_column | ... | result | warnings
1 | ... | result1 | NA
2 | ... | result2 | "Warning: something happened on id 2"
3 | ... | result3 | NA`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use `tryCatch`. I would show you the details, but there is no reproducible example here and I don't speak pipish.

Comment: Thanks, looking into that did the trick, I'll expand this into an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `lapply` instead, so you can return a one-row `data.frame` with two columns each time and `rbind` that list of data frames again at the end.

```
df <- data.frame(a=runif(20)-0.5)

f <- function(x) {
    tryCatch ({
        data.frame(result=log(x), warning=NA)
    }, warning = function(w) {
        data.frame(result=suppressWarnings(log(x)), warning=w$message)
    })
}

res <- cbind(df, do.call(rbind, lapply(df$a, f)))
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @mpjdem's answer but staying with `sapply`:

`tryCatch.W.E` returns a list

```
>> tryCatch.W.E(log(-5))
$value
[1] NaN
$warning
<simpleWarning in log(-5): NaNs produced>
```

In conjunction with `sapply`this results in a matrix and the original task can be solved by

`my_df %>% cbind(t(sapply(.$id_column, function(x) {tryCatch.W.E(my_function(x))})))`